# change if/else block to Polymorphism based on type

Tags: java, asynchronous, lambda, completable-future

I have the following approach :

1- How to use polymorphism to replace the If/else block bellow :

```
abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements GenericDao<T> {

    protected Properties queryStatement;
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    Map<Long, T> domainContainer;

    @Autowired
    public GenericDaoImpl(Properties queryStatement, DataSource dataSource) {
        this.queryStatement = queryStatement;
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.domainContainer = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public abstract Map<Long, T> execute(List<Long> entities);

}

public class AddressDTO extends GenericDaoImpl<AddressData> {
public class EntityDTO extends GenericDaoImpl<EntityData> {
```

and here is the Factory :

```
public class FactoryCreator {
@Autowired
private EntityDTO entityDTO;
@Autowired
private AddressDTO addressDTO;
<T> CompletableFuture<Map<Long, ?>> someFactory(Class<T> type, List<Long> entities) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        T classType = type.newInstance();
           if (classType instanceof PersonEntity) {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> addressDTO.execute(entities));
        } else if (classType instanceof EntityMaster) {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> entityDTO.execute(entities));
}elseIf....



 <T> CompletableFuture<ConcurrentHashMap<Long,intoSomthing>> createDocsFromType(Class<T> type) {

  return  someFactory(type)
          .thenApply(result-> converter.convert(result,intoSomothing))
          .exceptionnaly(throwable -> {/* handle exception ;*/ 
           return null;});

}
```

Calling this Chain this way : (ParallelEntities contain all Domains)

```
EnumSet.allOf(ParallelEntities.class).forEach(type -> {
            try {
                FactoryCreator.createDocsFromType(type.getType(), entities,docs);
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
               //logging
            }
        });
```

as you can see I am calling those separably in a loop and writing in same doc sequentially I want to change this to be more fluid!

Comment: Why do you want different executors? What is it about your solution that you don't like?

Comment: 1 )Basically what is happening right now :  task 1 (1db call 1 conversion) in 1 thread than waiting (join())
than executing 2nd task wait , 3rd task ... ntask
I wanted to be non blocking in a way : task1 (than apply)-> task2 ->task3
 -> taskn  : Combine.
Or another approach  all task running if 2 are done I can apply combine on them ? Idont know which is better and if it make sence?
2) I was asking if it is better to use for each task a different excutor ?

Comment: I don't see any blocking calls in the code you provided. Is there more relevant code? Because this one is non blocking. Sequential, but still non blocking. Would you like to fire off multiple jobs and then wait on all of them?

Comment: That's all the relevant code I didn't provide the combine method 
I was wondering If I was missing any feature of CF to achieve more parallelism in this case ?! is I/O bound  block me from achieving the parallelism?!
the 2nd approach was more to add the combine method  as soon as 2 tasks where finished instead of waiting till the end and start the combination in a loop  what do you think? thanks!